# fs.readFile() not read the whole files and everytime the read contents missing few parts

Tags: node.js, file, readfile

I just met a strange problem of fs.readFile() in my program. The file is not big(only 500k in size), it is a JSON.stringify(obj) string. I am trying to read it out and pass it to the front-end. 
While in the callback of fs.readFile("/path/filename", "utf8", function(e,data){}).I only got in-complete string.

```
    fs.readFile("/path/filename",'utf8', function (err,data) {
            if(err) {
               throw err;
            } else {
               let str = JSON.parse(data); // it will throw error by saying "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"
            }
        });
```

Have you met this problem？　What's the solution to read the whole/complete file?
PS:  I have manually checked the file contents, it is good and completed JSON string.

Comment: When you say you manually checked the file, did you do so yourself, or using something like http://jsonlint.com/

Just trying to rule it out.

Comment: @Alec Bennett, I used the sublime text editor to open the file and check the file contents, which is a complete json string. It is good.

Answer (score 5):

I just figured out what did I do wrong in my program. My trigger signal of reading file been sent "too fast" before the writing file not completely finished. I set some timeout just 100ms solved this problem and I can read out the complete json string to parse into object.

Comment: Instead use promise